# How to add new indexes 'SAFELY' to a table on the Production Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, non-clustered-index

I consider adding some new Indexes on a table that is in the Production Db. and my concern is 'how to make it without having an impact on the users'

**Question**: (If it is not a BAD Idea) How can I be sure that it would not harm/impact the users to add extra indexes on a table in PRODUCTION Db. that has more than 5 million records?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enterprise you can specify ONLINE = TRUE when you add the index.

Comment: If you don't have Enterprise: In my experience it takes the same time to roll back adding an index as it took to get there. So if you do book out a maintenance window of say 30 minutes to do the change, I would always cancel the transaction half way (15 minutes) to give enough time to roll back and have the table accessible when you window is over.

Answer (score 0):

By creating the index in ONLINE mode you will have minimum impact on the table locking (milliseconds) but you must have SQL SERVER Enterprise edition.

I am not recommending to create index on production with offline mode to a big table because you are going to lock the whole table and the creation of the index will be dependent from how busy is sql server. But anyway - if you are confident that your production is super fast, you create it.